Dynamic Title for Mass Filter visual in Power BI
I want to apply Dynamic Title to Mass Filter visual in Power BI report. The visual is set to be personalised,so the user can change the field of the visual. I want that the title of the visual gets changes once the field for that visual is changed. E.g. If I change the field of the visual from City to Country, then the Title should be changed to Country.
In the image shown, like once the City field is selected, then the title of the visual should be changed to City.

I don't believe there is a way to do this as you have it. However, you can achieve something similar by using Field Parameters.
With the approach of using Field Parameters, your end user wouldn't use Personalize to change the field of the Mass Filter. Instead, they would use a slicer to select one from a predefined list of dimensions. For example, the Field Parameter could have City, Country, and any other dimensions. Your end user would simply select the desired option from the slicer.
If using this approach, then you would set the Title of the Mass Filter to be that of the Field Parameter.
